# How to restore /root/.bashrc as sudo su is giving segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: sudo, bashrc

I've a dedicated remote web server. I messed up `/root/.bashrc` file by adding `source /root/.bash_profile`. It core dumps on sudo su.

```
$ sudo su
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I can't login to server via ssh using root as well.

I can't do `sudo su`.

I can reboot server into rescue mode.

How do I restore .bashrc file?

Comment: @steeldriver You are genius. It worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `sudo su -c 'exec /bin/bash --norc'` should work as well in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's rarely any reason to use `sudo su`.

You can get a root shell with `sudo -s`, or a root login shell (equivalent to `sudo su --login` / `sudo su -l` / `sudo su -`) using `sudo -l`. In the case of `sudo -s`, the shell run is that given by the `SHELL` variable if set, or otherwise the shell specified by the invoking user's password database entry.

So if you have messed up your `/root/.bashrc` some of the options you can try are:

1. invoke a non-bash interactive shell directly e.g. `sudo sh`
2. invoke a non-bash interactive shell via `SHELL=/bin/sh sudo -s`
3. invoke bash directly, skipping the resource file, `sudo bash --norc`
4. temporarily rename the troublesome file e.g. `sudo mv /root/.bashrc /root/.bashrc.old`

In principle, you could also invoke a root login shell with `sudo -l` since bash login shells read `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc` **HOWEVER** the default Ubuntu configuration sources `$HOME/.bashrc` from `$HOME/.profile` in order to give interactive login shells and non-login shells the same look & feel. It would work if you have a non-default `/root/.profile`, or a `/root/.bash_profile` or `/root/.bash_login` that avoided sourcing the broken `.bashrc`.